# reply_count attribute missing from tweet object

Tags: python, twitter, count, tweepy, reply

I am trying to retrieve the count of replies for a particular tweet(using tweet.retweet_count). But I am getting attribute not found error. Seems this attribute is missing from the tweet object.But when I check in the documentation of tweet object, its listed and should have been available. Am I mssing something?

documentation - https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object

I am using python and following is my code:

```
for tweet in alltweets:
    outtweets.append([tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode("utf-8"),tweet.place,tweet.source,tweet.reply_count,tweet.retweet_count,tweet.favorite_count,tweet.retweeted,tweet.lang])
```

my outtweets list is empty :(
tried with many tweets

Comment: using:

api = tweepy.API(auth)

alltweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200)

Comment: In Twitter v2 it is now possible to get the reply_count field without a premium account: https://blog.twitter.com/developer/en_us/topics/tips/2020/understanding-the-new-tweet-payload.html

Answer (score 4):

Even though `reply_count` is documented to be available on the `Tweet` object, it is, unfortunately, a part of the **premium API**:

> That field is only offered in the premium and enterprise API tiers and we need to do better at documenting this restriction.

([reference](https://twittercommunity.com/t/new-tweet-updates-reply-count/97891))

Comment: Complementary reference: https://twittercommunity.com/t/reply-count-quote-count-not-available-in-statuses-lookup-answer/95241/5